# How to replace text in SQL request into combination of ASCII characters?

Tags: mysql, sql, text, replace, ascii

What I want is simple: having a `TEXT` field in table I want to get each of its characters converted into one from array of ASCII `[☺, ☻, ♥, ♦, ♣, ♠, ♂, ♀, ☼]` with a conversion as simple as possible: given char as int, mod 9. Is such thing possible in MySQL and how to do it?

Comment: That's the weirdest ASCII I've ever seen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS wtf;

DELIMITER | 
CREATE FUNCTION wtf( str TEXT ) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN 

  DECLARE wtf_chars TEXT DEFAULT '☺☻♥♦♣♠♂♀☼';

  DECLARE i, len, wtf_len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret TEXT DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE c CHAR(1);

  SET str       = CONVERT(str USING ascii); 
  SET len       = CHAR_LENGTH(str);
  SET wtf_len   = CHAR_LENGTH(wtf_chars); 

  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID(str, i, 1); 
      SET ret = CONCAT(ret, SUBSTRING(wtf_chars, (MOD(ASCII(c), wtf_len) + 1), 1)); 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 

  RETURN ret; 

END | 
DELIMITER ;



SELECT wtf(`your_text_field`) FROM `your_table`;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just some guideline, I'm know just the mysql basics.

You need `set` variables 
Do string functions `substring`, `ascii`, `concat`
and a `while` loop

I don't know how you handle that weird `array` in mysql. Help say array doesn't exists.

```
col = '123456';
declare v_max int unsigned default 1000;
declare v_counter int unsigned default 1;
declare myChar varchar(1);
declare result varchar(100) default '';
declare myAscII  int;

-- get the lenth of the string
select CHAR_LENGTH(col) INTO v_max;

while v_counter < v_max do  
   -- get each char ascii  
   select ASCII(SUBSTRING(col, v_counter , 1)) INTO myAscII;

   -- get the array index 
   set myAscII = myAscII MOD 9;

   -- get the array value /*dont know how you handle this*/
   set myChar = WEIRD_ARRAY[myAscII]

   select CONCAT(result, myChar) into result;

   set v_counter = v_counter + 1;
end while;
```